# My PHP form is sending blank entries when the page loads/refreshes

Tags: php, phpmailer

My PHP contact form is working properly and sending info to my email when a user enters valid data into fields and hits submit, but it is also sending me a blank email every time I load the page containing the form. I'm thinking it may have something to do with my submission conditionals:

Submit button code:

```
       <div class="col-md-12 submit-button">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message" />
            <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>
       </div>
```

Form_process.php send code:

```
 if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' ){
  $message_body = '';
  unset($_POST['submit']);
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
  }  
  $to = 'admin@domain.com';
  $subject = 'contact form submitted';
  if(mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
      $success = "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.";
      $name = $email = $organization = $phone = $message = '';
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to check if the form is submitted before execute the send email script.

First add a name to your submit input

```
<div class="col-md-12 submit-button">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message" />
    <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>
</div>
```

Then wrap your send email code inside a if, check whether the $_POST['submit'] is presented

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // your send email code
}
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted my answer, can you explain your reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the form was submitted, so you don't run the code when you load the form.

```
if (isset($_POST{'submit'])) {
  // All the code that processes the form goes here
}
```